# How to model interpretations of rap music

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I just started working on a website that will help people understand what rappers are talking about. Users will see the lyrics to a rap song and they'll be able to click certain lyrics to see an explanation. Here's a screenshot (you can also check out the site itself [here](http://rapexegesis.com/songs/Cam-ron/Killa-cam)):

[alt text http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/6882/clocal.png](http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/6882/clocal.png)

(Original lyrics censored; [click here](http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/650/picture10vwr.png) to see them)

Anyway, my question is how to model these annotations in my application. Right now, I'm storing the lyrics and annotations as one big blob of HTML in this format:

```
<div class="lyrics">
  With the goons I spy
  <a href="#note1">Stay in tune with ma</a>
  <a href="#note2">She like damn
  This the realest since 'Kumbaya'</a>
  Kumbayay Killa Cam my lord 
</div>

<div class="annotations">
  <div id="note1">
"Ma" refers to ladies, generally, and specifically also the woman singing the hook;  "Stay in tune" is a musical metaphor: he literally stays in tune with the singer and also in the sense that he has game.
  </div>
  <div id="note2">
Kumbaya is a campfire singalong.
  </div>
</div>
```

and then processing it with this method for output:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers

  def annotated_lyrics
    lyrics = read_attribute('annotated_lyrics')
    return if lyrics.blank?

    require 'hpricot'
    doc = Hpricot lyrics

    doc.at('.lyrics').inner_html = doc.at('.lyrics').inner_html.strip
    doc.search("a[@href^='#note']").set('class', 'tooltip').each do |t|
      t.inner_html = t.inner_html.strip
    end
    doc.search("div[@id^='note']").set('class', 'annotation').each do |a|
      a.inner_html = auto_link(a.inner_html.strip, :all, :target => '_blank')
    end
    simple_format doc.html.strip
  end
end
```

and the rest I do with jQuery and the fantastic [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) plugin.

This works fine for display, but since my application doesn't know about the relationship between annotations and lyrics, it will be hard to, say, add an interface for updating an individual annotation inline (or at all, really).

On the other hand, I don't really know the best way to represent this in ActiveRecord. I suppose a song could "have_many" annotations, but how would I represent which lyrics were annotated? I could store the start and end word index, but this seems painful and sensitive to minor changes in the lyrics.

Comment: Rap meets RoR. The apocalypse is here.

Comment: beautiful application. Congratulations.

Comment: Please use different lyrics in this question. I'm sorry, they are simply NOT appropriate for this type of website, and I have edited them out until you can post more appropriate lyrics.

Comment: Okay, I edited out all the naughty words!

Comment: Thanks, I retracted my downvote and replaced it with an upvote, because I do like the question.

Comment: best site ever. can't wait to use it.

Comment: The site is "done", btw -- check it out: http://rapexegesis.com

Comment: unforgiven3: Censorship blows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about presenting the lyrics like this (with thanks to the People's Champ)?

```
Well it's that [grain grippa][1] from Houston, Tex
That bar sippa, that bar no plex
I'm straight up outta that [Swishahouse][2]
Where G. Dash write all the checks
So [check the neck, check the wrist][3]
I'm balla status from head to toe

[1]Referring to the wood grain steering wheel common to luxury cars
[2]Swisha House is the record label Paul Wall records for
[3]"Look at my watch and necklace because they are expensive"
```

Just an idea, I was inspired by the markup used to add comments on this site.

So, for the database, create Lyric, LyricLine and Annotation tables. Annotations have LyricLineIds, StartChar and EndChar values and a Meaning or Description field. LyricLines are the text of each line, related to the Lyric entity by LyricIds. Lyrics store song info, language info, whatever.

This format should be pretty easy to generate off of the database and has the benefit of being more "human readable" than XML and editable in-place, so you can test it a lot easier before you have to develop a whole UI.

I have this question favorited, and look forward to watching the site progress. Interesting work!

Answer (score 3):

1. Tokenize your lyrics, so that you can identify a word in the lyrics by using e.g. a line and word number. Another option is to use character positions for your annotations. In any case, as always, take care of the character encoding of the lyrics.
2. Further, never touch the lyrics anymore. Better not store them as html, but as xml or as plain text.
3. Don't annotate within lyrics. Use a model wherein you can attach a position in the lyrics to an annotation. Use stand-off annotation.

Stand-off annotation will allow you to add more features over time, such as letting many users annotate the same lyrics. Generating the HTML you store as a blob is easy to do from stand-off annotations.

You might be interested in the (xml) data models of annotation tools that are quite well known among linguists: e.g. MMAX2 and Callisto. These are easily convertible to database models.

Answer (score 1):

XML would be a great model also.

```
<song>
  <title>...</title>
  <lyrics>
    <verse>
      <line>Well it's that <dd>grain grippa</dd><dt>Referring to the wood grain steering wheel common to luxury cars</dt> from Houston, Tex</line>
      <line>That bar sippa, that bar no plex</line>
      <line>I'm straight up outta that <dd>Swishahouse</dd><dt>Swisha House is the record label Paul Wall records for</dt></line>
      <line>Where G. Dash write all the checks</line>
      <line>So <dd>check the neck, check the wrist</dd><dt>"Look at my watch and necklace because they are expensive"</dt></line>
      <line>I'm balla status from head to toe</line>
    </verse>
    <chorus>
      <line>...</line>
    </chorus>
    <verse>...</verse>
    <repeat-chorus/>
  </lyrics>
</song>
```

Pretty easy to edit and update. Creating a UI for it probably wouldn't be difficult. If you were opening up the creation of records to the public, you might change `<dd>` and `<dt>` to `<phrase>` and `<definition>`. But dd and dt are the HTML standard which is why I used them in the first place. This would enable you to use straight CSS to style it up with a little love from JavaScript to make it look awesome. (BTW The site is awesome.)

Comment: This is basically what we do (except we convert it to a markdown-like syntax for editing. E.g., `You ever see someone who roll with [Mayweather](46513), rhyme like [Ricky Hatton](46514)` (the numbers are annotation ids)). Glad you like the site!

Answer (score 0):

Your first instinct to setup associations with a song having many annotations would definitely work. Two potential approaches to storing the start and stop annotation indexes:

1. Store the start and end line that the lyric occurred on (count the linebreaks in your lyric file)

or

2. Store the start and end word boundary (or just space) that denotes the annotation. This would at least let you correct most typos without breaking the annotation index.

Answer (score 0):

As for linking annotations and lyrics you can have several approaches:

1. Link as proposed above annotations to exact places in lyrics (eg. line numbers, words,
   characters).
2. Make dictionary phrases/words <-> annotation. Just before displaying you search
   dictionary and insert into page annotations. 
   If speed or specificity is concern each entry in
   dictionary can be tagged by relevant songs. If you want your annotations to be robust to
   small changes in lyrics than while finding matches in lyrics for annotated phrase use 
   [Longest common subsequence metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence).
3. Combine #1 and #2